# Python Instaloader web crawling HTTP error code 401

Tags: python, web-crawler, instaloader

I am trying to download photos with a list of short codes from Instagram by using `Instaloader` module in Python. After several successful downloading, I received the following error:

**ConnectionException: JSON Query to graphql/query: HTTP error code 401.**

My code sample is the following:

```
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()
for i,v in shortcodes.items():
     post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, shortcodes[i])
     L.download_post(post, target=post.owner_username)
```

I would appreciate for any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it works earlier but not working now you may have reached the API rate limit. In this case, you may need to wait until the rate limit is reset or adjust the rate at which you are making requests to stay within the limits.